# Calling a method using jni: Bad JNI oop argument

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to call a method using jni (java native interface), but it crashes when I'm calling the method. I read the documentation, so I found out that I need to use objects of the type "jvalue" as parameters, but, how can I convert a jobject/j to a jvalue?

Here's my current code:

```
    jclass unsafeClass = (*env).FindClass("sun/misc/Unsafe");
    jfieldID unsafeObjFieldID = (*env).GetStaticFieldID(unsafeClass, "theUnsafe", "Lsun/misc/Unsafe;");

    jobject theUnsafe = (*env).GetStaticObjectField(unsafeClass, unsafeObjFieldID);

    jmethodID defineClassID = (*env).GetMethodID(unsafeClass, "defineClass", "(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;");

    jsize dataSize = (*env).GetArrayLength(arr);
    jbyte* data = (*env).GetByteArrayElements(arr, NULL);
    jstring name = (*env).NewStringUTF("Test");
    jint n0 = (jint) 0;

    // In this method it crashes ._.
    (*env).CallObjectMethod(theUnsafe, defineClassID, name, data, n0, dataSize, classLoader, NULL);
```

hs_err_pid (if it would help): http://paste.reflex.rip/okugaluyok.go

EDIT: I found the startparam "-Xcheck:jni", now I got a little error message.

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: Bad JNI oop argument
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old and outdated, but this seems to be the only thread with this particular error message.  I do not have the same setup as the OP but I found that when I tried to do this

```
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcls, mainMethod);
```

I would receive this same error.  This was to invoke the main static method of my main class.  It also produced the same error message "Bad JNI oop argument".

I fixed this by creating a new (empty) jobjectArray and passed it to the method, and it fixed my error.

```
jobjectArray args;
args = env->NewObjectArray(0, env->FindClass("java/lang/String"), 0);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(jcls, mainMethod, args);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
(*env).CallObjectMethod(theUnsafe, defineClassID, name, data, n0, dataSize, classLoader, NULL);
```

This is not correct. Did you make it up? Don't do that. Read the [JNI Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/design.html). It should be:

```
env->CallObjectMethod(theUnsafe, defineClassID, name, data, n0, dataSize, classLoader, NULL);
```

For completeness, in C it should be:

```
(*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, theUnsafe, defineClassID, name, data, n0, dataSize, classLoader, NULL);
```

Comment: Changed that, but it still crashes at the same position. I've added hs_err_pid in the main question. :)